# Magento add custom code in xml statement?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I've created code necessary to add a custom item to every cart, and all seems to be *ALMOST* working as intended.  The code gets the items in the cart, and formulates XML that is sent over to a 3rd party in a request, and parses the response back to my code into an array. The response array is then added to the cart as a unique item with a specific, preordained SKU.

The only trouble that I'm facing is that when I do this, it doesn't seem to update the subtotal in the cart.  For example:

I put in an order in the cart for one item costing $421. This one item is put into an XML statement that is sent over to the 3rd party to get a certain price for a "bond" that is based on the cost of all items in the cart. The response sends the cost of the bond back as $12.63 and the subtotal of the two items in the cart is $433.63 as intended.  Then, after playing with the quantity of the $421 item, I'm starting to see some odd things...

I change the number of the item to 5, and click "UPDATE CART". I get a return value of $63.15 on the bond, but the subtotal shows that I'm adding $2,105 (the price of 5 items) with $12.63 (the price of the original bond) for a total of $2,117.63. I click "UPDATE CART" again, and it then shows the total of $2,168.15.

This happens every time I change the quantity. I get the previous "bond" price added to the current subtotal, and it takes me two clicks of "UPDATE CART" to get the price caught up.

So, I was thinking *if there was a way to add the code I've created **BEFORE** it runs anything else, I'd be able to close that gap.*  Am I doing this correctly? What is the best way to add my code previous to any other code that has been put in the XML to call forth this page?

***EDIT***

To explain further, this is the code block I'm using:

```
    $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    if ($buySAFEcost > 0) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $bs_cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();

        $bs_my_product_id  = $product->getIdBySku($bs_sku);
        $bs_my_product     = $product->load($bs_my_product_id);

        $params = array( 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $buySAFEcost );
        $bs_cart->addProduct($bs_my_product,$params);
        $bs_cart->save();

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0); // ADMIN_STORE_ID
        $bs_my_product->setPrice($buySAFEcost);
        $bs_my_product->save();
        // Redo the totals?


        $cartModel->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
        $cartModel->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $cartModel->getQuote()->collectTotals();
        $cartModel->getQuote()->save();


        // $cartModel->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1); // DISTRO_STORE_ID
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    }
```

I feel like I'm killing an ant with a sledgehammer here, but the subtotals remain constantly one step behind my actions. *Am I putting this in the wrong section of code, perhaps?*

Comment: FYI, Magento has its [own StackExchange site](http://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you. I've posted this question there as well, now.

Comment: I'm also willing to say that if there is a way to reset the shopping cart subtotal after this process is performed, I'd also be interested in how to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the totals need to be collected on your quote object.  You can see how Magento does this itself in the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save()` method:

```
    $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
    $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
    $this->getQuote()->save();
```

The billing and shipping address impact the taxes in the totals.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to give it a shot right now.  Wish me luck!

Comment: I've added my current block of code to the question, and edited. I'm sure I'm doing SOMETHING wrong, but I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: I don't see you updating the price of the bond in this code - perhaps it's happening somewhere else?  Seems like something's out of order.  Also note, the $bs_cart->save(); call does the same thing as the $quote->getBillingAddress()... etc calls, so you don't need both.

Comment: Yes, $buySAFEcost is updated earlier in the code. This is one of two items returned from the XML request response.